# Edge: how to make autofocus work with refresh button

Tags: microsoft-edge

I'm here looking for a workaround for a weird Edge issue.

Edge browser doesn't seem to respect autofocus any time input focus is on the browser chrome. Minimal repro: copy the below HTML into an index.html file, open index.html in Edge, click on Refresh button in Edge browser bar.

**Expected:** input has focus and I can start typing immediately.

**Actual:** focus remains on the Refresh button. If I type ENTER it refreshes the page again. I have to manually tab across the Edge chrome to get to my browser page.

Note: Edge works fine when I refresh via Control-F5. Only the Refresh button has this problem.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Focus tester</title>
</head>
<body class="bg-light">
  <form>
  <input autofocus id="dataEntry" placeholder="Enter some data"></input>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this a known issue, and is there a workaround? My real scenario involves barcode scanners which programmatically send ENTER keys after reading data, and I want to avoid having the web page reload when someone scans immediately after loading or refreshing the page.

Thanks,

Max

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug, you should [report it](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/new/).

[This bug report](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/101198/) seems to encounter the same issue you are experiencing, but the status on this is 'fixed'.

Using the above test case, I tested in Edge 15,16 and 17 and all three experienced your bug (reloading via the UI refresh button, focus remains within the UI, however via the keyboard it works as expected).

I can't see any settings within Edge where the user can change this behaviour.